# How to insert an image in CollectionFS?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collectionfs

I'm trying to create a collection of images using the CollectionFS in meteor. I used the following code from https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/wiki/Insert-One-File-From-a-Remote-URL

```
        var url='data/2.jpg';
        var newFile = new FS.File();
        newFile.attachData(url, function (error) {
            if (error) throw error;
            newFile.name("testImage.jpg");
            Images.insert(newFile, function (error, fileObj) {});
        });
```

The above code is written in the startup function in the 'js/server.js' file & the image it is referring to is 'js/data/2.jpg'.

But it doesn't seem to work & throws the this error:

```
Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\[username]\WebstormProjects\test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\data\2.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `ENOENT` is an abbreviation for “**E**rror **NO ENT**ry“. You receive this error because the file `2.jpg` cannot be accessed or does not exist in the directory `C:\Users\[username]\WebstormProjects\test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\data\`.

If you want to insert a file from a remote URL, you need to supply an accessible URL, for example:

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})]
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        var url = 'http://www.panderson.me/images/lena.jpg';
        var newFile = new FS.File();
        newFile.attachData(url, function (error) {
            if (error) throw error;
            newFile.name("lena.jpg");
            Images.insert(newFile, function (error, fileObj) {
                console.log(error);
                console.log(fileObj);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I assume that you don't want to insert a file from a remote URL. If this is the case, place your file in the `private` directory and change the variable `url` to: `"assets/app/lena.jpg"`.

```js
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})]
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        var url = "assets/app/lena.jpg";
        var newFile = new FS.File();
        newFile.attachData(url, function (error) {
            if (error) throw error;
            newFile.name("lena.jpg");
            Images.insert(newFile, function (error, fileObj) {
                console.log(error);
                console.log(fileObj);
            });
        });
    });
}
```